# Restarting cancelled tasks in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, java.util.concurrent, futuretask

I am creating tasks with [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and adding the Futures to a list as below in my ThreadFactory class.

```
private static List<Future> futures;
........
ScheduledFuture sf = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(obj, delayInMilliSec, repeatPeriod, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

futures.add(sf);
```

Now when I want to cancel all the tasks , I do as below

```
public void cancelAllTasks(){

  Iterator<Future> fi = futures.iterator();

  while(fi.hasNext()){

     fi.next().cancel(true);
  }

}
```

**Now how do I restart these tasks at a later point of time ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a future is cancelled, the task cannot be resurrected at a later stage. A quick look at [javadoc will explain](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) the contract of the Future.

To restart the tasks, schedule them again with the executor.

Answer (score 2):

AFAik you can not , you need to reschedule them